# CSS3 transition difference between browsers in coverflow like slideshow

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transitions

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nweBD/

I'm trying to create a Coverflow like slideshow using CSS3 transitions, but I'm getting different results from different browsers:

FF; shows wanted behaviour (right slide animates from right to center).
CHROME; first positions right slide at left side, then animates to center.
IE10; does nothing

HTML:

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="middle">middle</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: -150px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.middle{
  text-align:center;
  z-index:2;
  height:120px;
}

.left{
  text-align:left;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color:green;
}

.right{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:right;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  margin-left:0;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Nice job on your first question.  Adding a fiddle is huge.

Comment: @Jess thnx. Any chance you could help out with this?
-
I think I've figured out why the transitions are wonky; because of the left and right 'auto' value and browsers not being able to transition to and from 'auto': http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/#left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is indeed that browsers have no, or at best, various results for animating to and from 'auto'.

To fix this, I have re-written the CSS to not use `left:auto; right:0;` but `left:100%; margin-left:-300px`. This means I only have to animate the `left` and `margin-left` property, and I don't need to reset them to the default `auto`. The negative margin is the same amount as the width of the element, which pulls it back to the desired position, giving the same result as `right:0;`.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nweBD/3/